# Multi-tier architecture Sequence Diagram Advice

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm creating a Multi-Layer Pattern supplier sequence diagram with CRUD functionality. Supplier web form(using client browser) will go through the REST Service starting from the Supplier Controller, continue to Supplier Service and Supplier DAO.

It is made up of four layers:

1. User Interface (Supplier Web Form) (Random Computer/Device)
2. Controller (Supplier Controller) (Server 1)
3. Service (Supplier Service) (Server 1)
4. Data Access Object (Supplier DAO) (Server 2)

The default when a user open the supplier page, user will see the list of supplier data on a grid. If user press "add button" then the new input-form will be pop-up, and continue to save the data through the Rest Controller(Server 1). If user "double-click" the grid(means "edit") then the edit-form will be pop-up and automatically be filled by the selected data from the grid, and continue to save the data through the Rest Controller(Server 1). If user highlight the grid and press "delete button" then the data will be send to the Rest Controller(Server 1) to be deleted.

Is that right ? Do I have to add some object/message ?

Here is the image.
[image: Sequence Diagram]

Comment: How should anyone know?

Comment: Is there a pattern that you are trying to implement that you want advice on?

Comment: I'm using multi-layer pattern which consists of 4 layers, i have edited my question for more details.

Comment: Your Supplier Service doesn't seem to be involved at all in this sequence diagram.

Comment: Currently, the Supplier Service is not being used. I  reserve the layer(Supplier Service) for future complex calculations. Do i need to do so ?